# Mac OS/X system sound storage?

Tags: macos, audio

I want to find the system sounds on my Mac.  Where are they?

Answer (score 1):

Look under (in this order):

Macintosh HD / System / Library / Sounds

They are in .AIFF format.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks!  That does help.  But where is the `wang` sound that happens when you drag 'n drop a file from one place to another?